# When does the quotient metric reduce to the infimum of the distances of only two points?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Given a metric space $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$, the quotient (pseudo-)metric on $X/\sim$ is defined as follows:

- $d'([x],[y]) = \inf \left \{ d(p_1,q_1) + d(p_2,q_2) + ... + d(p_n,q_n)\right \}$

where $[p_1] = [x], [q_n] = [y],$ and $[q_i] = [p_{i+1}]$.

Under what circumstances does this reduce to the much simpler equation

- $d'([x],[y]) = \inf \left \{ d(p,q): [p] = [x], [q] = [y] \right \}$

?

It appears to work for $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^m$ for $m \leq n$, but I'm curious about the general case.

Comment: Always by the triangle inequality?

Comment: No, you usually need to consider all chains for it to work out.

Comment: The first metric is less than the second metric @gunnar. The triangle inequality does not work, as $p_{n+1}$ may be distinct from $ q_ n$

Comment: For instance, consider the real line with the absolute value as a metric, but where the numbers 0 and 1 are identified and nothing else. By the simpler expression, the distance between -1 and 2 is still |2--1|=3, but by the more complicated one involving chains, you can consider the chain (-1, 0, 1, 2), for which the sum of successive distances is 1+0+1=2.